# flutter test passed if i test it one by one but failed when i run it together

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Here is my script

```
void main() {
  final mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();
  testWidgets('Intial test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
      navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
    ));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byType(WelcomeScreen), findsOneWidget);
  });
  testWidgets('Open login form', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
      navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
    ));
    await tester.tap(
      find.byKey(Key("login_btn")),
    );
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any));
    expect(find.byType(LoginScreen), findsOneWidget);
  });

  testWidgets('Open Register form', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
      navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
    ));
    await tester.tap(
      find.byKey(Key("register_btn")),
    );
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any));
    expect(find.byType(RegisterScreen), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Here is the test i want.

- When i tap `login_btn` go to `LoginScreen`
- When i tap `register_btn`  go to `RegisterScreen`

So, when i try it together the tests  are failing. But when i run it one by one , there is no problem. How can i fix it?

Comment: I had a similar problem where I Solved by setting/removing awaits.
I would suggest that you try to click debug in the main class and set a break points where the test is breaking so you can see which variable is breaking your test. In my case some variables weren't being set lacking of awaiting some operation.